# Meteor: How to access Template's Instance key in Blaze directly (without helper)?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

```
Template.Demo.onCreated(function() {
    this.test = 'Text';
});
```

How to access that template's instance `test` key in Blaze **directly** (*without creating a helper function*)?

`{{Template.instance.test}}` seems not to work (it was suggested [here](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/template-instance)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with current versions of Blaze. That being said, you can simulate this by declaring a single global Template helper function, like:

```
Template.registerHelper('instance', function () {
  return Template.instance();
});
```

Just define this once in a common client location, and you can then reference `instance` in any of your Template's. So you could reference your `test` variable like:

```
{{instance.test}}
```